# Java: prevent auto-decoding of encoded String

Tags: java, string, decoding

I have an encoded String like this:

```
17298457,abcdef/17298529,ghijklm/17298562,opq%2Frstu
```

and want to split it on the "/".

In the last part, there is a encoded "/" as "%2F".

The result is

```
[17298457,abcdef , 17298529,ghijklm , 17298562,opq , rstu]
```

The problem is, that Java decodes the string on the fly as soon as i pass it to another method (split method e.c.)

Do someone have a good idea how to work around that?

thanks a lot!
monk

Comment: Java itself isn't going to magically decode strings. Some code has to be doing it. You haven't provided any context to indicate what might *actually* be decoding it though.

Answer (score 1):

Not for me....

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String s = "17298457,abcdef/17298529,ghijklm/17298562,opq%2Frstu";
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("/")));
    }
}
```

gives

```
[17298457,abcdef, 17298529,ghijklm, 17298562,opq%2Frstu]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String test = "17298457,abcdef/17298529,ghijklm/17298562,opq%2Frstu";

    String[] args2 = test.split("/");

    for (int i = 0; i < args2.length; i++) {

        String[] args3 = args2[i].split("%2F");

        for (int j = 0; j < args3.length; j++) {

            if(!args3[j].trim().startsWith(",") && j != 0)
            System.out.print(" ,");
            System.out.print(args3[j]);
        }

    }
```

OUT PUT - AS U WRITTEN -

17298457,abcdef17298529,ghijklm17298562,opq ,rstu